# How to use ssh2_connect to connect to multiple connections?

Tags: php

I have this php code to connect to ssh2, but I'm trying to make it so it connects too multiple hosts, instead of 1

```
$ssh = ssh2_connect('host', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'root', 'pass');
```

Comment: what do you mean by that?, you can make another `$ssh` .. `$ssh3`

Answer (score 0):

You can always make as much variables as you want

```
$ssh = ssh2_connect('host', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'root', 'pass');


$ssh2 = ssh2_connect('host2', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($ssh2, 'root', 'pass');


$ssh3 = ssh2_connect('host3', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($ssh3, 'root', 'pass');
```

`$ssh`, `$ssh2` and `$ssh3` will be 3 connections.

Comment: ok well ill give this a try cuz i also have other codes that connect to these